# Show that $\lim _{x\downarrow 0}\ x^{\alpha }\log \left(x\right) = 0$ for $\alpha > 0$

Tags: limits, analysis, logarithms

How can one show that

$$\lim _{x\downarrow 0}\ x^{\alpha }\log \left(x\right) = 0$$

for $\alpha > 0$?

I know that the logarithm function is slower than any power, hence it loses when coupled to powers, meaning that $x^\alpha \log (x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$, but that's just a repetition of what's given...

Comment: You should be able to notice that you can reduce your problem to the equivalent and simpler limit $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x\log x=0$$ and putting $x=1/t$ it is reduced to proving that $$\lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{\log t} {t} =0$$ Now use inequality $\log x\leq x-1$ with $x=\sqrt{t} $ and apply squeeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha>0$
$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x^{\alpha} \log x \rightarrow 0\times \infty$$
By L'Hospital Rule, we get
$$L=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\log x}{x^{-\alpha}}= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\log x}{x^{-\alpha}}= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1/x}{-\alpha x^{-\alpha-1}}=
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} -\frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

If $y = \dfrac1{x}$
then

$\begin{array}\\
x^a\log(x)
&=\dfrac1{y^a}\log(\dfrac1{y})\\
&=-\dfrac{\log(y)}{y^a}\\
\end{array}
$

and since
$\lim_{y \to \infty} \dfrac{\log(y)}{y^a}
=0
$
for any $a > 0$,
$\lim_{x \to 0} x^a \log(x)
=0
$
for any $a > 0$.